# When adding traces to fig=px.scatter() does it have to be added with fig.add_traces(go.Scatter())?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

When adding traces to fig=px.scatter() does it have to be added with fig.add_traces(go.Scatter())?

I ask this because it gets very confusing with the subtle differences, that are a PIA to remember (for me), between px.scatter and go.scatter. Also, is it better/more comprehensive to use one or the other?

I feel like I should be able to add the traces the same way the original ones were created? i.e., fig.add_traces(px.Scatter()). That would cut down on remembering all the inputs. Am I missing something?

here is my sample code:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4],'y':[1,1,1,1],'z':[10,10,10,10],'custom':[30,30,30,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4],'y':[2,2,2,2],'z':[15,15,15,15],'custom':[40,40,40,40]})

fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 x='x', 
                 y='y',
                 size='z',
                 size_max=10,
                 custom_data=['custom'],
                 color_discrete_sequence=['red'],
                 )

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "x: %{x}",
        "some custom data: %{custom_data[0]}",
    ])
)

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(  x=df2['x'], 
                            y=df2['y'],
                            mode='markers',
                            customdata=df2['custom'],
                            marker=dict(size=7, 
                                        symbol='circle', 
                                        color='blue',
                 )))

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "x: %{x}",
        "some custom data: %{customdata}",
    ])
)
fig.show()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Plotly express is just an abstraction layer built on top of plotly graph objects. Plotly express uses plotly graph objects internally. The idea is that for doing common things you can write more concise code with plotly express than if you'd use graph objects directly. But there might be cases where you're not able to do something in plotly express, but you can do it with plotly graph objects.

Comment: I don't think it matters that much in general if you use graph objects or plotly express. But one might be easier to work with than the other depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plotly express only solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df  = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4],'y':[1,1,1,1],'z':[10,10,10,10],'custom':[30,30,30,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4],'y':[2,2,2,2],'z':[15,15,15,15],'custom':[40,40,40,40]})

fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 x='x', 
                 y='y',
                 size='z',
                 size_max=10,
                 hover_data=['custom'],
                 color_discrete_sequence=['red'],
                 )

fig2 = px.scatter(df2, 
                 x='x', 
                 y='y',
                 hover_data=['custom'],
                 color_discrete_sequence=['blue'],
                 )

fig2.update_traces(marker=dict(
                                size=7, 
                                symbol='circle', 
                                color='blue',
                     ))

# Add all the traces from fig2 to fig
fig.add_traces(fig2.data)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's the `go.Scatter()` part that you find confusing in `fig.add_traces(go.Scatter())` then you can use this instead:

```
fig.add_scatter
```

Or you can use any of the other methods that will reveal themselves by running `dir(go.Figure())`, such as:

```
 add_bar
 add_barpolar
 add_box
 add_candlestick
```

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
dir(fig)
```

Comment: This is perfect. thank you! Why is there a go.scatter()? is it more comprehensive than just px.scatter?

Comment: When I use fig.add_scatter(), it looks like it eliminates the option to color the added scatter points differently than the original scatter points?

Comment: @someds Regarding your first second question, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. If you take the time to write it up as a new post then I'll make sure to take a look at it. Regarding your first question in the comment above, I would say that go.Scatter is a more fundamental building block than px.scatter. Both return a go.Figure object, but are used differently. The main objective of Plotly Express is to provide a simple syntax for complex charts. Take a look at [Introducing Plotly Express](https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-plotly-express-808df010143d)